# Why is my arraylist only changing the data in one element?

Tags: android, listview, arraylist, android-contacts, phone-number

I have 3 arraylists. **The ultimate goal is to change all phone numbers in my listview to contact names.**

**fetchContactNumbers()** returns a list of all phone numbers (31) in my device.

**fetchContactNames()** returns a list of all contact names (31) in my device.

**newList** has 6 phone numbers in it.

What I'm doing is changing the numbers within newList to the corresponding names in fetchContactNames() according the the position of fetchContactNumbers(). So since fetchContactNumbers()'s and fetchContactNames()'s elements are in the right order, newList will look for a match in fetchContactNumbers(), index that position, then use that position in fetchContactnames() to set the number in newList to its representative name.
Here is an example I've made to test for a clearer picture:

**Example to test as a console app:** http://pastebin.com/pApHNkXa

Here is the code in my activity:

```
    // change displayed numbers into contact names
    for(int i = 0; i < newList.size(); i++){
        int index = fetchContactNumbers().indexOf(newList.get(i));
        if(fetchContactNumbers().contains(newList.get(i))){

            newList.set(i, this.fetchContactNames().get(index));
        }
    }
```

From there, newList is passed into my CustomAdapter class to populate my listview.

The problem with the above code (which is correct based on my example) is that when I run this in my app, **only newList.get(3) changes to its correct name.**

Does anyone know why only one name is changing an not all? I've checked logcat, and it displays the same thing with no errors.

Comment: you not thought to about use `HashMap` for this goal? When you have two arraylist of numbers and names, then your HashMap seems like much more better approach, `HashMap<Name, Number>`

Comment: @hawaii.five-0 how would I achieve this?

Comment: just create HasMap with Names and numbers, name will be key and number value and it will be more effective, simplier.

Comment: @hawaii.five-0 do you of a tutorial of how to do this? I've searched, but cant seem to find anything relate to my situation.

Answer (score 0):

You can construct your map as follows. Use a TreeMap instead of a HashMap if you value alphabetical sorting over efficiency.

```
    Map<String,String> contacts = new HashMap<String,String>;
    List<String> numbers = fetchContactNumbers();
    List<String> names = fetchContactNames();

    for(int i = 0; i < numbers.size(); i++)
    {
        contacts.put(numbers.get(i),names.get(i));
    }
```

Make sure you also import the HashMap and Map

`import java.util.HashMap;`

`import java.util.Map;`

Then just rewrite your CustomAdapter to work for a HashMap. [Here](http://www4.ncsu.edu/~kaltofen/courses/Languages/JavaExamples/jgl3.1.0/doc/api/com.objectspace.jgl.examples.HashMapExamples.html) are some examples on how to use the HashMap